Ошибка в PyCharm: typeerror unsupported format string passed to IPv4Address. __ format__
Возникла ошибка в программе по учебе. В IDLE программа запускается, возникает ошибка именно в PyCharm. Файл создан верно, путь к python 3.11 верный. Ни у кого из одноклассников проблем с кодом не было, только у меня...
Программа:
from ipaddress import *
net = ip_network('112.154.132.0/255.255.252.0', 0)
cnt = 0
for ip in net:
    ip2 = f'{ip:b}' # ошибка
    if ip2[:16].count('1') <= ip2[-16:].count('0'):
        cnt += 1
print(cnt)


Значит вы запускаете код вовсе не через python 3.11

Путь к файлу именно 3.11 (сейчас специально даже проверила), другой версии на компьютере у меня нет. Если бы был не 3.11 в IDLE бы тоже же не сработало скорее всего

"Если бы был не 3.11 в IDLE бы тоже же не сработало скорее всего" - вот как раз то, что в IDLE работает, а в PyCharm нет, указывает на то, что запускаете разными версиями Python. Сделайте import sys и print(sys.version) в начале кода, и посмотрите, что выведет при запуске в IDLE и при запуске в PyCharm.

«другой версии на компьютере у меня нет» — значит это неправда и на самом деле есть
